# WPF TreeView Hide certain Items

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to hide some elements being displayed in the TreeView by using the Enabled property from my ViewModel. I'm setting the Visibility to Collapsed using Data Trigger, but the problem is even though the items aren't visible it just leaves those lines empty.

My XAML:

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ResSummTreeView" Background="Gray" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:TreeItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Margin="0 5 0 5" Foreground="Wheat" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:KeyValue}">
                        
                        <Grid Margin="0 5 5 0" x:Name="KeyValueGrid">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Key}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0 0 15 0" Foreground="AliceBlue"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="LightGreen"/>
                        </Grid>

                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Enabled}" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="KeyValueGrid" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: Until you try to hide an item by playing with the tree control, you won't reach any decent success. WPF views play very well with viewmodels (MVVM), so that you have your model projecting the items to an intermediate (view)model. At that level, you should create ANOTHER hierarchy model, where the hidden items simply are skipped from the source model. The visual tree should bind to this "filtered" model.
With this technique you can realize with ease a ton of nice features, otherwise pretty hard to achieve via XAML.

Comment: @MarioVernari Thanks that works. I have got one more issue. Previously when I was hiding it from the XAML the tree header didn't collapse everytime the item is disabled. But with this approach the whole tree is closed everytime I update. Is there any solution to this ?

Comment: @Harxish: How do you "update"?

Comment: @mm8 I create a new observable collection in the view model and assign it to the binded property.

Comment: @Harxish: You should not create a new collection but update the existing one. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Previously when I was hiding it from the XAML the tree header didn't collapse everytime the item is disabled. But with this approach the whole tree is closed everytime I update. Is there any solution to this ?

The solution is to add and remove items from the existing `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of creating a new one as this will cause the control in the view to be reset.

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm first doing `TreeItems.Clear()`, then I'm iterating the source and doing `TreeItems.Add(new TreeItem(item.Header, item.GetEnabledItems()))`. TreeItems is my property which I'm binding to. This still collapses the tree.

Comment: What if you don't call `Clear()`?